# How to combine an array of png images like layers using C#?

Tags: c#, image, png, overlay, layer

I have an array of images named

```
image_<somenumber>_trans.png
```

All these images have transparent areas. The idea is that when put one on top each other
they will form a nice looking image. But I have been getting a weird GDI+ related error (“A generic error occurred in GDI+”)
and I have been going crazy. The code I'm using now can be viewed as below;

```
number_of_photos = 30;
Bitmap temp = new Bitmap("background.png");//some white background 640x480 pixels
temp.Save("temp.png", ImageFormat.Png);
temp.Dispose();
for (int photo_no = 0; photo_no < number_of_photos; photo_no++)
{
    Bitmap temp1 = new Bitmap("temp.png");
    Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(temp1);
    Bitmap new_layer = new Bitmap("image_" + photo_no + "_trans.png");
    //the images image_<photo_no>_trans.png are also 640x480 pixels
    gra.DrawImage(new_layer,0,0);
    temp1.Save("temp.png");//error: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
    temp1.Dispose();
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help in advance...

Comment: I think you can reuse the `Graphics ` instance by moving it outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Including the _exact_ text of the “weird GDI+ related error” would be extremely helpful to you in getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Is there anymore detail in the exception?  Does this happen with the same image every time, or can you try a different image and make it work (ie. start with image 1 instead of image 0 and does it still except)

Comment: @Donal The error is as I have already written is "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Comment: John: I took the libery to include that message in the text portion of your question as it wasn't immediately obvious that it was present already.

Comment: @Joey I am still a bit fuzzy on stackoverflow.com formatting is there a way to accept both slaks and swejtsys answers? As they both helped me to find my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to only save the image when the whole process is completed.

```
Image i = new Image(...)
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(i)
for(...)
{
    g.Draw(...)
}

i.Save(...)
```

Comment: Than I get an `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.` error

Comment: Ok found the problem. I used some of @slaks comment too

Answer (score 1):

Writing `new Bitmap(filename)` will lock the file until you dispose the `Bitmap`.
Therefore, you can't overwrite the file.

Comment: Either load the file into a MemoryStream, then create an `Image` from that, or save as a different name.

Comment: Do you need to resave the image with each itertion?  Can't you complete the compilation and then save the bitmap?