# C# Image flatten to single image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I need to write some code to manipulate an image in c#.
I have an image with an alpha channel and I need to combine into one image. 
Original files are in .png format (but the format is not a problem). How can I flatten to a new image with a single layer?

Comment: So you need to combine two images into one? Have you tried drawing one into the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine an array of png images like layers using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809309/how-to-combine-an-array-of-png-images-like-layers-using-c)

Comment: What do you have? One 32bit image and you want to convert to 24bit?? Or several images? Or do you want to use one image as the alpha channel of another image? Please explain your aim!!

Comment: I have several image in png format. I need to flattern it. Thanks